# How to set up an SSH Server on OS X

Tags: linux, macos, bash, ssh

I'm planning on making a Bash script that sets up an SSH server. The script is only meant to work on a computer running OS X. With the research I have conducted it seems like you have to use the GUI to enable SSH. Is their a way to enable SSH through Terminal and then create a script that does so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable it from the command line (or a shell script) with:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

You might also want to regulate access to the ssh service with the com.apple.access_ssh group:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a usernametoallow -t user com.apple.access_ssh
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a otherusernametoallow -t user com.apple.access_ssh
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a groupnametoallow -t group com.apple.access_ssh
```

...after which only usernametoallow, otherusernametoallow, and members of groupnametoallow will be able to ssh into the Mac.